# Nested SUM with OVER clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to understand how nested SUMs with OVER clause work in SQL. Let's say i have the following schema in my DB

```
Time(timeID, date, month, year);
District(districtID, districtName, region, state);
Delivery(destinationDistrictID, timeID, numberOfDeliveries);
```

and suppose that i want to calculate the (number of
deliveries of each region)/(number of deliveries of the state) on the same year. The query to do the calculation is:

```
SELECT region, year, (state), 
       SUM(NumberOfDeliveries)/SUM(SUM(NumberOfDeliveries)) OVER (PARTITION BY state, year), 
FROM Delivery del, Time t, District dis
WHERE t.timeID = del.timeID AND dis.DistrictID = del.destinationDistrictID
GROUP BY region, year, state
```

I can't understand how the PARTITION BY works in this case. Particularly i can't understand which data are passed to the analytic function (OVER clause).

Does the `PARTITION BY` works on the whole dataset or on the rows aggregated by the GROUP BY?

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions are set based, and generally evaluate *last* in the query, after everything else has evaluated.  Here is your call to `SUM()` again:

```sql
SUM(SUM(NumberOfDeliveries)) OVER (PARTITION BY state, year)
```

This will evaluate *after* the `GROUP BY`, at which point the intermediate table will have one record for each region, state, and year.  Your analytic function call sums the sum over a window of all regions in each state and year.  So your expression can be summarized as:

```
total number of deliveries in each region, state, and year /
total number of deliveries in each state and year
```